# Wordpress - How to get custom post type by slug?

Tags: wordpress, slug

I'm in a situation where I need to get a WP post (custom post type) and the only information I have is its slug. I don't know what custom post type it is, just that it's a cpt.

Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Previous one didn't work. Can you tell me what do you want to know about that post? For example, title, content etc. Currently, my code tells you about the post type and post id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$the_slug = 'post-slug-here'; // <-- edit it
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_name, post_type, ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '". $the_slug ."'" );
foreach ( $myrows as $myrow ) 
{
    echo 'Post Type: ' . $myrow->post_type . ' Post ID: ' . $myrow->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reaction, but I stumbled upon this. Be careful with such queries because it can be easely injected with SQL vulnerabilities whan you grab the slug from your url.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post comments as answers. Participate on the website and soon you will have enough reputation to post comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure all the custom post types that were defined in your WordPress theme or plugins, it's probably better to use a dedicated function like `get_page_by_path()`. It will prevent users from trying to inject SQL in a query.

For example :
`get_page_by_path( 'slug_of_the_post', OBJECT, [ 'list', 'of', 'possible', 'types' ] );`

See [code reference of the function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/).